# Delete/Hide last X amount of characters in <p> tag

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, hide, ellipsis

I'm using a WP plugin and had no luck exploring source code specific to the plugin (Blog Filter Premium). It is automatically adding an ellipsis to the end of my description in a `<p>` tag, however, I don't believe it is using any CSS to do this as the ellipsis are actually in the html/paragraph itself.

```
<p class="blog_description">Here is an example of my description with a period at the end and then subsequent ellipsis automatically being added....</p>
```

Is there a way with CSS or to inject `<script>` into the `<head>` to have my `.blog_description` paragraphs remove the final 3 characters or hide them? Or at the very least color them white so that I can get rid of these ellipses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could split the string by the delimeter ('...'), remove the last item, then join it back together again.

```js
let srch = '...';
document.querySelectorAll('.blog_description').forEach(el => {
  if (el.innerText.indexOf(srch) > -1) el.innerText = el.innerText.split(srch).slice(0, -1).join(srch);
})
```

```html
<p class="blog_description">Here is an example of my description with a period at the end and then subsequent ellipsis automatically being added...</p>
```

Comment: – This was pretty much perfect thank you! I added that script into the plugin js file. Only thing is it was taking away the final period as well, even though that was in my text, then an additional "..." making it a total of four periods. Not sure why it was removing all 4

All I did though was just add a space after my period so it break it up and we're golden. THANKS!